# Using github package in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I need to include a package from github in my Shiny app. How can I do this. When I create a .Rmd file I include the lines

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tvganesh/cricketr")
library(cricketr)
```

How do I do this in Shiny?

I tried to add the above 3 lines in server.R
But when I open the Shiny app, it remains grayed out. The Shiny app is fine when running locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install the package, here cricketr, *once* into your library. Your shiny app can then load it from there the usual way via `library(cricketr)`.

Just make sure that your installation directory and shiny's default agree. I prefer the default `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/` path for that.  You may have a default of a per-user directory so that shiny may not see. In that case, specifify the installation directory as an option.

Comment: Dirk - I did not understand. When you say install(cricketr), should I run the above 3 commands in my command prompt and not include them in server.R

Comment: My bad.  Meant library().